# NSMutableDictionary + NSMutableArray crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have an NSMutableDictionary called "myScheduleFullDictionary" set up like this:

```
  KEY             VALUE
"Day 1"         An NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries
"Day 2"         An NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries
"Day 3"         An NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries
```

etc.

I'm trying to parse it - basically grab one of the MutableArrays contained as the Value of one of the Keys.
Here is my code:

```
// First I make a mutableCopy of the entire Dictionary:
NSMutableDictionary *copyOfMyScheduleDictionary = [myScheduleFullDictionary mutableCopy];

// Next I grab & sort all the KEYS from it:
NSArray *dayKeysArray = [[copyOfMyScheduleDictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];

// I set up an NSMutableArray to hold the MutableArray I want to grab: 
NSMutableArray *sessionsInThatDayArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// Then I iterate through the KEYs and compare each to the one I'm searching for:
for (int i = 0; i < [dayKeysArray count]; i++) {

    NSString *currentDayKey = [dayKeysArray objectAtIndex:i];        
    if ([currentDayKey isEqualToString: targetDayString]) {
        NSLog(@"FOUND MATCH!!!");

        // I log out the NSMutableArray I found - which works perfectly:
        NSLog(@"found array is: %@", [copyOfMyScheduleDictionary objectForKey:currentDayKey]);

        // But when I try to actually grab it, everything crashes:
        sessionsInThatDayArray = [copyOfMyScheduleDictionary objectForKey:currentDayKey];
        break;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
-[__NSDictionaryM name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5fb2d0
```

Not sure why its pointing out "name" as the "unrecognized selector."   "name" is an NSString property of a "Session" class I declared and am working with - could *that* be related somehow?

Any insights?

EDIT:

Here is my "SessionObject" class definition:

```
@interface SessionObject : NSObject


@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *speaker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *location;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate *startTime, *endTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *notes;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *dayOfConference;


@end
```

Comment: Where is `name` been used?

Comment: Are you sure that's the line causing the error? Have you added an exception breakpoint? It doesn't make sense that the log should work, but not the next line.

Comment: how do I add an exception breakpoint? You mean a try-catch block?

Comment: In Xcode's breakpoints sidebar, at the bottom, there's a plus. You can add exception breakpoints via that. They're breakpoint that trigger as soon as an exception is thrown (not at all the same thing as @catch).

Comment: WAIT. I think you're right. I think its crashing after all that. Hang on...

Comment: breakpoints sidebar? is this on the left or right? bottom or top? Console?  I don't see it...

Comment: Left side above the files list. It's the second icon from the right

Comment: @rdelmar - YES, NICE. I just did what you suggested (adding an exception breakpoint) - it takes you right to the line that's causing the crash. Brilliant. Who knew? :-)  (And I've been using XCode for 2+ years now!)  And you're right, the offending line causing the crash IS after the code I posted in my question. I know what i did wrong now - thanks!

Comment: I suppose I give @rdelmar credit for the "right" answer? :-)  Wait - you didn't post a reply - what do I do?

Comment: @sirab333 You wait for the user to post their comment as an answer and accept that. If they don't do it after a few days, then you should post the answer yourself and accept it so that people know that the issue has been solved.

Comment: Just for the record, that message means that you "passed" the "message" (called the method) "name" on an object of type NSDictionary.  This indicates that where you're calling "name" the object you're using for the call is not the type you think it is.

Comment: try this[[copyOfMyScheduleDictionary objectForKey:currentDayKey]objectAtIndex:0];

Comment: otherwise somehow cast it to array [copyOfMyScheduleDictionary objectForKey:currentDayKey];

Answer (score 1):

```
-[__NSDictionaryM name]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c5fb2d0
```

This means that you are trying to call `name` on an `NSMutableDictionary` where as you should have called it on an object of class `SessionObject`. Check the line where you are calling something like `myObject.name` or `[myObject name]` and see if `myObject` is of type `SessionObject` and not `NSMutableDictionary`.

Here `__NSDictionaryM` denotes the `NSMutableDictionary` type.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where your bug comes from - but what are you doing there? Why don't you just write

```
sessionsInThatDayArray = [myScheduleFullDictionary objectForKey:targetDayString];
```

??? That's what NSDictionary is there for - you don't search for things by hand, you just call the method to look up the key. Instead you copied the dictionary, you extracted all the keys, you sorted the keys, you iterated through them one by one until you found it - and then you called objectForKey!!!

Apart from that, in the debugger set a breakpoint on all Objective-C exceptions. It will stop when the offending code is called, so no need to search for a needle in the haystack.